Flutter ShowOnScreen not working properly in NestedScrollView
I used Expandable in NestedScrollView and add ScrollOnExpand to fully display the widget that exceeds the screen.
The problem is that triggering ScrollOnExpand when the Widget exceeds the upper area of ​​the screen will cause the screen to scroll to the top:
NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
            ),
            pinned: true,
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverList.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                key: ValueKey('test1 $index'),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpandableNotifier(
                  key: ValueKey('test2 $index'),
                  child: ScrollOnExpand(
                    key: ValueKey('test3 $index'),
                    child: Column(
                      key: ValueKey('test4 $index'),
                      children: [
                        ExpandableTheme (
                          data:ExpandableThemeData(
                            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                          ),
                          child: ExpandablePanel(
                            key: ValueKey('test5 $index'),
                            header: Text('test $index'),
                            collapsed: Text('test collapsed $index'),
                            expanded: SizedBox(height:100,child: Text('test expanded $index')),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ExpandableButton(child: Text('button $index') ,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )


I found a similar question in the author's Github, but it didn't work.

The issue happens because the screen scrolls incorrectly when the widget expands beyond the top boundary. You can solve the problem by putting on screen controls.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';

class MyExpandableList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyExpandableListState createState() => _MyExpandableListState();
}

class _MyExpandableListState extends State<MyExpandableList> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
            ),
            pinned: true,
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverList.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                key: ValueKey('test1 $index'),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: ExpandableNotifier(
                  key: ValueKey('test2 $index'),
                  child: Builder(
                    builder: (context) {
                      var controller = ExpandableController.of(context);
                      return Column(
                        key: ValueKey('test4 $index'),
                        children: [
                          ExpandableTheme(
                            data: ExpandableThemeData(
                              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                            ),
                            child: ExpandablePanel(
                              key: ValueKey('test5 $index'),
                              header: Text('test $index'),
                              collapsed: Text('test collapsed $index'),
                              expanded: SizedBox(
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: Text('test expanded $index')),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ExpandableButton(
                            child: Text('button $index'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (controller != null) {
                                setState(() {
                                  controller.toggle();
                                  if (controller.expanded) {
                                    WidgetsBinding.instance
                                        .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      RenderBox renderBox = context
                                          .findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                                      Offset offset =
                                          renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                                      double y = offset.dy;
                                      _scrollController.animateTo(
                                        _scrollController.offset + y - 100,
                                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                                      );
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thanks for your answer, but I'm sorry I can't use your code. Adding a Controller for CustomScrollView causes NestedScrollView to lose control of it. And ExpandableButton can't use onPressed.
